# Property 'execute' does not exist on type 'Pool'

Tags: typescript, mysql2

I am using mysql2 with TypeScript. I am facing a problem with the Pool interface. Look at the following code -

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  database: "nodirokkha",
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  maxIdle: 10, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as `connectionLimit`
  idleTimeout: 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
  queueLimit: 0,
});
```

When I execute query using `pool.execute`, it says `Property 'execute' does not exist on type 'Pool'`. I typecasted to any by using `pool as any`, and the function works fine without the types.

What exactly is the problem here? Why is there no `execute` function in the `Pool` interface?